# Strict Lyapunov Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to solve next problem:

Let $f:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow\ \mathbb{R^n}$ $\in C^1$ such that $f(0)=0$ end $\left\langle x,f(x)\right\rangle <0$ $\forall x \neq0$. Prove that $x\rightarrow\left|x\right|^2$ is a strict Lyapunov function for the system at $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

By telepathy I guessed that we study the system $$\frac{d}{dt} x=f(x).$$

We write by definition (for $|\cdot|^2$)

$$\frac{d}{dt} |x|^2 =\frac{d}{dt} \langle x,x\rangle = 2\langle f(x),x\rangle<0,$$
Hence indeed, $x\to |x|^2$ is a strict Lyapuoniv function (I leave for you to verify that this function is positive for $x\ne 0$ and  $\mathcal C^1$ everywhere).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write that I am analyzing the system x'=f(x). Anyway thank you

Comment: @Célio if this answer replies your question, then it would be great to upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: Telepathy, that's funny...